# Correctly Guessing The Coin Toss

Tags: probability, random-variables, conditional-probability, random

> In a football​ game, the sides in the soccer field are determined on the basis of a single coin flip by the referee and the team which correctly guesses the flip result gets its desired side. What is the probability that a team will have to wait until its 8th game to get its desired side?

I am stuck with this question, any help would be much appreciated!

I thought, $\frac{1}{2}^8$ but it is wrong.

Comment: The way the question is asked, I would agree with $1/2^8$.  That is, of course, assuming that our team we care about is asked to guess first every time and the opposing team answers next with the other choice, that the coin is fair, that both teams preferred side is the same and so our team guessing the coinflip wrong necessarily means that they don't get their desired side, and so on...

Comment: That's the odds the team doesn't *win a flip* until the 8th game. But there's always the possibility that the team loses the flip, and then their opponent picks the side they *didn't want* anyway. Without any additional information, you could argue the team gets their desired side 100% of the time if they win the flip, and 50% of the time if they lose the flip. But that ignores some practicalities that there often is a side that's preferred by both teams, so it may not be not a great model of reality. We can't answer without knowing the odds of getting the desired side after *losing* the flip.

Comment: I can't think of anything rather than (1/2 to the power of 8). Very strange...

Comment: it took me a second for it to click, but I'm typing the answer right now. just hold on. :)

Comment: I am waiting for it. Thanks in advance :) @aperson

Comment: you're welcome. :)

Comment: I figured it out by realizing that it is aking if they actually get their desired side on the 8th game, not  if they finally win the toss on the 8th game.

Comment: Thanks for the answer though, but I don't think the answer is (1/2)^16. Because it wants an answer with four decimal points. :( @aperson

Comment: @NuclearHoagie nitpick... "*That's the odds*" should have been "*That's the* **probability.**"  The words *odds* and *probability* have two different definitions in mathematics.  The odds of flipping heads on a fair coin is $1:1$.  The probability of doing so is $\frac{1}{2}$.  They may both convey the same information but they do so in different formats.

Answer (score 0):

it depends. if they play against a team who usually picks the side that 'our' team wants again and again, than they are more likely to wait until their 8th game, but then they might lose the toss again. the other way around is the exact opposite, because if both teams want different sides, than they will probably get their chosen side first game. it's most likely to happen if each team who wins the toss chooses randomly, in which case the chances are still as low as 1/2^16.

Comment: If both teams want different sides, it is *impossible* for the team to go even a single game without their desired side. Even if we assume an adversarial opponent that always picks the side you want, the odds certainly can't be any worse than the odds of not winning a flip in 8 games - it can't be any worse than 1/2 ^ 8. It doesn't make sense that your team would have a desired side, win the coin flip, and then choose the side they *don't* want.

Comment: I know that. this was for if the other team chose randomly.

Comment: If the other team chooses randomly, the probability of getting your preferred side should be *higher* than if they choose adversarially. If they choose adversarially, the chance that you don't win a single flip and don't get your desired side in 8 flips is 1/2 ^ 8 - that's the worst possible case. You're saying that if the opponent picks randomly, somehow it's even *less likely* to get your preferred side than if your opponent always specifically chooses it (1/2 ^ 16 < 1/2 ^ 8). But in the random case, you still have a chance after losing the coin flip, in the adversarial case, you do not.