# Probability of a Coin Toss

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

I am stuck with this question, I thought $(\frac{1}{2})^7$ but it is wrong. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
In a football​ game, the sides in the soccer field are determined on the
basis of a single coin flip by the referee and the team which correctly
guesses the flip result gets its desired side.

a) What is the probability that a team will have to wait until its 7th
game to get its desired side?
```

Comment: What makes you think it is wrong?

Comment: The program says it is wrong, unfortunately...

Comment: I can't think of any other answer than this. @drhab

Comment: I think that something is wrong with the program.

Comment: [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4047274/correctly-guessing-the-coin-toss) has appeared before.  The problem is that the problem is poorly phrased.  There is some probability that you will lose the coin toss but the opposing team will hand you your desired side anyway.  Of course, we have no information regarding that probability.  We could make a guess as to that, if we wanted to.

Comment: To make it into a better question one could add something like "each time, the teams choose there 'desired side' uniformly at random".  Or at least, require that the opposing team does.  You need to assume something though.   Your answer is correct if you assume the two teams prefer the same side.  On the other hand, if the two teams prefer opposite sides then our team *always* gets the side it wants.

Answer (score 1):

your result looks correct to me. It is a geometric distribution

$$\mathbb{P}[X=x]=(1-p)^{x-1}\cdot p=\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^6\cdot\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the program says it is wrong... @tommik

Comment: @tommik: Shouldn't it be $$\frac{1}{7!}$$?

Comment: What makes you think that way? @Jim

Comment: @smith.john1919: I added an answer with my reasoning

Comment: Thank you for your effort, I am not sure whether it is correct and can't test it because I have limited number of tries. @Jim